# Strange plot created based on two numpy arrays and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Now I just want to plot a line graph based on two numpy arrays. My x and y are both two (150,1) arrays. After running the following code:

```
plt.plot(x,y)
```

What I get is:
[Line graph based on two numpy arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBz35.png)

Hence I am so confused. What do those connected lines represent? I just want one line which goes through all of the points. Any help would be appreciated!

---

For the dataset, X is just a fixed (150,1) numpy array and y is computed based on the following polynomial function:

```
def PolyCoefficients(x, coeffs):
""" Returns a polynomial for ``x`` values for the ``coeffs`` provided.

The coefficients must be in ascending order (``x**0`` to ``x**o``).
"""
o = len(coeffs)
y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    value = 0
    for j in range(o):
        value += coeffs[j]*x[i]**j
    y.append(value)
return y
```

The coefficients have been computed and what I want is just a line go through each point of (x,y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pairs of `x` and `y` represent the points on your graph. With plt.plot() you join the points with a line. If the array `x` is not in order, what you have is a line that goes back and forward across the graph. To avoid this you should order the `x` array, and the `y` accordly. Try with:

```
new_x, new_y = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y)))
plt.plot(new_x,new_y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But actually my x is fixed and y is just the output from a polynomial function based on x. The coefficients have already been computed... Does the order of these two arrays change during the computation?

Comment: If you have just these 2 lists, order them for the graph. I've added some code to the answer, try it and see if it works

Comment: You are welcome, dont forget to acecpt the answer :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work